# Redo a create or replace in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, create-table

I have the following problem:
I have used the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myschema.public.table1 as (SELECT * FROM myschema.public.table1 BEFORE(OFFSET => -60*4*15) WHERE MARKET = 'ES'
)
```

I still had the filter `MARKET = 'ES'` in and now all the entries that are unequal MARKET = 'ES' are gone. Can I still undo this?

Answer (score 0):

As you issued create or replace, the original table is dropped. So you need to rename your existing table and undrop the original table. Then you may re-run your timetravel command:

```
alter table table1 to table1_bak
undrop table table1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myschema.public.table1 as (SELECT * FROM myschema.public.table1 BEFORE(OFFSET => -60*4*15) )
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/undrop-table.html